# What is the best way to find DML references to objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Something I have always struggled with is finding DML references to tables in SQL server at the company I work. We have our code held in TFS source control and deployed to a shared development environment so I can search using either file searching or t-sql code. The challenge I have is that I can easily find all references to a table name but I can't find a good way to filter further to a particular statement like UPDATE/INSERT/MERGE.

A large challenge in this is that the company I work at has a lot of dynamic SQL so I think the best method will be some form of text searching. The other challenge is that coding is written as each developer sees fit so an UPDATE statement will not be written in any 'standard' way throughout the code base - i.e. the table name could be on the same line as the DML statement or on a separate line.

I have been able to use some basic regular expression searching in Visual Studio to find instances where the keyword is on the same line as the table name but I don't know how to search for it being 'close'.

Has anybody else faced this issue and found a good way to search for this information? What I would love is a tool where you put in a t-sql reserved keyword and an object name and the tool shows you all references.

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic. Quick search: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/ and http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx

Comment: How is tooling off topic if that is the best way to find what I'm after? I know there are such tools but I don't see how they enable what I'm after.

Comment: You said `What I would love is a tool where you put in a t-sql reserved keyword and an object name and the tool shows you all references.` and `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: Anyway you simply don't find 100% bullet proof tool. Dynamic-SQL that is built based of table values and you cannot detect it unless you execute the code.

Comment: Ok thank you I did not realise asking for tool recommendations was off-topic

Answer (score 0):

One way to at least see all the code across Views, SP, Functions, etc is to run this:

```
--will show you all source code from procs, views, functions etc
select *
from syscomments 

--or better to join it on sysobjects and display only view source code for example
select o.id,o.name,c.text 
from syscomments c 
    inner join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
where o.[Type] = 'V'
```

I found once I have all of this, I can then do easy searching in Excel or via Notepad++.

I hope that helped.